# Structuring a simple array of rows

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a very simple cms in laravel and i have everything done except the sorting of parent and child pages.

My table looks as followed:

```
page_id | page_title | page_content | page_parent
```

I realise there is plenty of solutions I can just include in my project, but it just seems crazy to import something for such a trivial task!

I imagine that the process is something like:

```
Build array via a foreach loop

1. Add first row to array
2. Check if the id of this row, is in page_parent row
3. If it is -> get the id of the matching row and add to the array 
4. If it is not -> add the next row to array
5. Repeat step 2.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `page_parent`? is it like a linked list or can pages have children and their children can have children (etc)?

Comment: page can have children, that's all, i have 6 pages, 3 of them are child pages

Comment: Can you describe what you want to return?  Do you want a multidimensional array ( 1st level parents, 2nd level children ) ?

Comment: Im not sure im going about this in the right way. Im building an unsorted list with the array that is returned. The array is sorted based on page_id, so i have: frontpage, news, first child of news, 2nd child of news, contact and so on. So i suppose it should be a multidimensional array, and than loop that out to an unsorted list. Thanks for your time btw, this is an aspect of programming im struggling with and trying to grasp!